# Internal or external Backup Disks

Tags: backup

I want setup a small energy efficient server for a home office. It has a system M2 boot drive, two disks in RAID-1 and two disks for a 2-way rotating full data backup.

My question is how dangerous is it to keep the backup copies in the same computer? I don't care about house on fire or computer gets stolen, just for technical damage like power spikes, overheating or other things.

Putting them in an external case is unfortunately not a good idea as long as there is no programmable power switch available for cheap money.

Comment: You might as well not have a backup at all!

Comment: `Putting them in an external case is unfortunately not a good idea as long as there is no programmable power switch available for cheap money.` - I don't understand that statement. What does that mean?

Comment: I mean that i want to turn the external disks on only while doing backups. Therefore is would any kind of programmable power switch.

Comment: Your internal drive doesn't have a programmable power switch either. What difference does it make if it's drawing power in one case or the other?

Comment: It adds another idle power supply and a controller.

Comment: Why don't you just use USB drives for your backups?

Answer (score 0):

I'd think the most power efficient answer would be to keep the disks internal and allow power management to spin them down when not in use. As for safety, a UPS or surge protector will help with power spikes. If overheating is an issue, the server has insufficient cooling/airflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do numerical calculations.  One chassis fan (with sufficient CFMs) has sufficient airflow.  A second fan in series (one blowing in, another blowing out) provided redundancy.  Then a server should be just fine in a room that any computer should be happy in - at 100 degrees F.

Neither power strip protector nor UPS even claims to protect hardware.  UPS provides temporary and 'dirty' power so that unsaved data can be saved in a blackout.

Power strip protector can even make surge damage easier if a properly earthed 'whole house' protector is not installed.  What is the most critical words in that last sentence?  Not protector.  A most critical item to protect from that anomaly is a low impedance connection to earth ground.

Best protection at that computer is already inside its power supply.  But again, only if selected using specification numbers.  Most PSU recommendations will be subjective - therefore bogus.